# Python: read outlook mail

Tags: python, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a script that uses the library "imbox" to get all the emails and their attachment, but since microsoft has disabled basic authentication obviously it does not work.

For what I understood I first need an access token using the "msal" library and then probably use "imaplib" that supports "XOAUTH2".

Does anyone have simple example code to get the access token in a non-interactive way?
When I get the token, can I simply use "imaplib" by specifing "XOAUTH2" as authentication mechanism?

I already tried with:

`result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(username=username, password=password, scopes['https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All'])`

but i get the error: AADSTS65001

If i try with the interactive mode (to test):

`result = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes['https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All'], port="x")`

I get the error: AADSTS7000218

Answer (score 0):

```
result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(username=username, password=password, scopes['https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All'])
```

Microsoft does not advise customers to use it as it's less secure than the other flows. For more information about why you want to avoid using this grant, you can, for instance read the following article which explains [why Microsoft is working to make passwords a thing of the past](https://news.microsoft.com/features/whats-solution-growing-problem-passwords-says-microsoft/).

Read more about that in the [Username Password Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) article.